# BOOTSTRAP tooltip multi instances not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying using tooltip() and opening multinstances as follow:

```
$("*").tooltip({
    selector: "*[rel=tooltipTOP]",
    placement: "top"
  });
  $('*').tooltip({
    selector: "*[rel=tooltipBOTTOM]",
    placement: "bottom"
  });
```

then in html i do for example

```
<a rel="tooltipTOP" data-original-title="top">tooltip TOP</a>
<a rel="tooltipBOTTOM" data-original-title="bottom">tooltip BOTTOM</a>
```

so tooltip TOP is ok but tooltipBOTTOM doesn't shows the tooltip ... why?

i tryed also to put specific class for tooltipBOTTOM but it doesn't works, it instances only the tooltipTOP rel :/

JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/BH2GM/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, why are you doing that based on `rel`? You really should use class.

```
<a class="tooltipTOP">tooltip TOP</a>
<a class="tooltipBOTTOM">tooltip BOTTOM</a>
```

and then

```
$(".tooltipTOP").tooltip({
    placement: "top"
});
$(".tooltipBOTTOM").tooltip({
    placement: "bottom"
});​
```

EDIT: But if you have to use rel, here's the solution:

```
$("*[rel=tooltipTOP]").tooltip({
    placement: "top",
    trigger: "hover"
});
$('*[rel=tooltipBOTTOM]').tooltip({
    placement: "bottom",
    trigger: "hover"
});​
```

Comment: i tryed, it does works only for 1 instance for me :/ i'm using latest vers of jquery and bootstrap :/

Comment: Hmm...could you give us a link? Cause this should work - I mean it does work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_foto/BH2GM/)

Comment: OK, can you then create a jsfiddle with more of your site, so we can see where it goes wrong? As you can see on my fiddle - my solution does work so there must be something else going on...

Comment: cause i was planning a HUGE html refactoring !!

Comment: What's important about this answer and what it left out is the question's usage of the `selector` option, which takes care of elements that were inserted into the DOM _after_ `tooltip()` had been called. I think @Pavlito's answers (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25229652/151509) would be a better fit here.

Answer (score 7):

***HTML***

```
    <ul class="bs-docs-tooltip-examples">
                  <li><a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</a></li>
</ul>
```

***JS***

```
$('a').tooltip();
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abaksheyev/4QawG/1/)***

Comment: please see DEMO, please check that you include all necessary files

Comment: i'm using bootstrap.min.js and it is updated to latest version

Comment: try use bootstrap-tooltip.js, for more details please take a look at link DEMO in my post

Comment: but it isn't inside bootstrap zip :/ , i include bootstra.js cause it includes all the js bootstrap files

Comment: it it hard to say what is wrong... i see that my demo works correctly. Sorry but i am not sure that i can help in this situation. May be is it worth to change your file with bootstrap-tooltip.js?

Comment: If you have downloaded the latest version of Bootstrap, both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js contain all of the plugins listed on this page. this is from bootstrap official doc

Answer (score 3):

I find that problem is with Jquery selector.

If you have 2 instances of tooltip you can do this

```
$("body").tooltip({
    selector: "*[rel=tooltipTOP]",
    placement: "top"
  });
  $('html').tooltip({
    selector: "*[rel=tooltipBOTTOM]",
    placement: "bottom"
  });
```

Note jquery selectors are different. First is **BODY** second is **HTML**

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is maybe that you use your tooltips on elements that are dynamically generated?
I had the same Problem an used "live" to get it working...

```
$(document).live("mouseover", function () {
    $('.tooltipTop').tooltip({
        placement: "top"
    });
    $(".tooltipBottom").tooltip({
        placement: "bottom"
    });
    $(".tooltipRight").tooltip({
        placement: "right"
    });
    $(".tooltipLeft").tooltip({
        placement: "left"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it solved by increasing z-index of element on which i assigned tooltip.